# How to remove featured images from posts

Tags: post-thumbnails

Somehow my theme doesn't recomend featured images. That being said, how can i remove featured images from posts?

Comment: what do you mean by your theme doesn't recommend featured images? Can you explain a little more? are you customizing any theme?

Comment: I also don't quite understand why the featured image it's not recommended to use. They've asked me only to trust their word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use Developer tools in Google Chrome and see what section is responsible for displaying the featured image on post page.
2. Open page.php or single.php (relevant file responsible for generating single page) and delete that code.

Keep a backup of the file before making any changes :)

Comment: If you're just removing existing code, remember you can comment it out with //